# Does load balancer also sequence the jobs before they are distributed?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, scheduler, distributed-computing, job-scheduling

I am having on a problem where a load balancer (nginx) is used to distribute the multitude of jobs among a set of servers. Beyond scheduling of the jobs using well known balancing algorithms (e.g. round robin, hash based etc), I have a requirement where I need to mark/tag each job that is being scheduled.

My assumption is that, in addition to the scheduling of jobs, load balancer is also a piece of block in the system where jobs are passing through in order (in whatever order they arrive), and it naturally acts as a serializer before they are distributed.

Is my understanding correct in the sense, that the marking/tagging that I am looking for can be achieved at load balancer?

I have neither used or implemented any load balancer so far, and hence not aware of internal functioning of a load balancer is concerned. If my assumption of serializer is correct, then I can hope to achieve the tagging/marking of jobs.

I also appreciate any additional information on how such tagging/marking of jobs can be achieved using a load balancer (e.g. using Nginx server).

Comment: What do you mean by “tag”?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, a 'tag' is any metadata e.g. a timestamp at which a job has arrived or a sequence number.

Comment: Can't you add a specific custom header value depending on which is destination server? For example, add this proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host; to each request: request will be marked with destination host, different for each balanced one.

Comment: @DvTr thanks for suggestion. I think it will certainly help and answers one question. My other question is: does load balancer processes all these requests in the order they are received (i.e. in serial order) before they are dispatch to individual workers?

Comment: As I know, yes it is. Default balancer action, round-robin, acts as each request arrives, it is sent to worker: so, requests stack acts as FIFO, First In First Out, in order. Note that there's nothing before the balancer, just stack. Anyway, I dont know your specific conditions. In this case I understand that to make a testcase, using a custom created client or apache benchmark, will give you better understanding.